# How am I supposed to persist to SQL Server DB using Ember JS and asp.net MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ember.js

I have an example I found online (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/511031/A-sample-real-time-web-application-using-Ember-js) to start learning Ember JS and it's pretty cool, but I noticed it saves the data to the Ember .em file which isn't a DB like SQL Server or MySQL.

In what manner should I persist the data to the DB, let's say SQL Server. Below is the Controller code from the example which is called when the user hits the button to Add, Update, Remove items from a table:

```
namespace Ember.n.SignalR.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Ember.n.SignalR.DS;
    using Ember.n.SignalR.DTOs;
    using Ember.n.SignalR.Validators;
    using FluentValidation.Results;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
    using Ember.n.SignalR.Hubs;

    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/

        JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public string Read(Guid? id)
        {
            Result r = new Result { ErrorCode = 0, ErrorMessage = String.Empty };

            if (id == Guid.Empty || id == null)
            {
                r.Data = CrudDS<Customer>.Items.AsEnumerable<Customer>();
            }
            else
            {
                r.Data = CrudDS<Customer>.Items.Find(c => c.Id == id);
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, _settings);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
        public string Delete(Guid id)
        {
            Result r = new Result { ErrorCode = 0, ErrorMessage = "Delete customer successful." };
            var customer = CrudDS<Customer>.Items.First(c => c.Id == id);
            bool ok = (customer == null) ? false : CrudDS<Customer>.Items.Remove(customer);
            CrudDS<Customer>.Serialize(DateTime.Now);
            if (!ok)
            {
                r.ErrorCode = -1;
                r.ErrorMessage = "Could not find customer with id=" + id;
            }

            r.Data = customer;

            // Broadcast to all clients
            CustomerHub.Instance.Clients.All.remove(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer, _settings));

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, _settings);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
        public string Update(Customer customer)
        {
            Result r = new Result { ErrorCode = 0, ErrorMessage = "Update customer successful." };

            Customer item = CrudDS<Customer>.Items.Find(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                r.ErrorCode = -1;
                r.ErrorMessage = "Could not find customer with id=" + customer.Id + ".";
            }
            else
            {
                CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
                ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

                if (!results.IsValid)
                {
                    r.ErrorCode = -1;
                    r.ErrorMessage = results.Errors.First().ErrorMessage;

                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, _settings);
                }

                item.FirstName = customer.FirstName;
                item.LastName = customer.LastName;
                item.Email = customer.Email;
                item.Phone = customer.Phone;
                CrudDS<Customer>.Serialize(DateTime.Now);
            }

            r.Data = customer;

            // Broadcast to all clients
            CustomerHub.Instance.Clients.All.update(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer, _settings));

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, _settings);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public string Create(Customer customer)
        {
            Result r = new Result { ErrorCode = 0, ErrorMessage = "Create customer successful." };

            CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
            ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

            if (!results.IsValid)
            {
                r.ErrorCode = -1;
                r.ErrorMessage = results.Errors.First().ErrorMessage;

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, _settings);
            }

            customer.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            CrudDS<Customer>.Items.Add(customer);
            CrudDS<Customer>.Serialize(DateTime.Now);

            r.Data = customer; // Return current customer

            // Broadcast to all clients
            CustomerHub.Instance.Clients.All.add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer, _settings));

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, _settings);
        }
    }
}
```

Should I just add code to these functions to persist the data to the SQL Server DB? If so, do I persist to the SQL Server DB first then if it's successful update the .em file (which is what it is currently doing)? Or do I update the .em file first, then attempt to persist to the SQL Server DB and if that fails undo the update to the .em?

I can't seem to find any examples online that saves to the .em file as well as persist to an external DB like SQL Server or MySQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the .em file is there for demo purposes.

You should be able to change the CrudDS<> methods with your own methods to persist data, and the behavior from the front end should be the same.

Here's an example of a Post from a default action created by the WebAPI2 template:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Context.Add(customer);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = customer.Id }, customer);
}
```

You can see how the `!ModelState.IsValid` property is nearly identical to the `!results.IsValid` check from the example.

EntityFramework is doing basically everything, creating the object, and persisting to storage with `db.SaveChangesAsync()`.